# efficient way to find domino's board order

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a small domino's game that works this way: I'm given a `N*N` 4-tiles, and I need to order them so that every two adjacent tiles have the same number. The tiles may be rotated. For example, here is my 2*2 board:

```
a,b,c,d = [1,2,3,4], [7,9,6,2], [6,8,8,5], [3,5,0,0]
```

They can be visualized by:

```
print(print_2_tiles(a,b,'a','b'))
print(print_2_tiles(d,c,'d','c'))

##############
#**1**##**7**#
#4*A*2##2*B*9#
#**3**##**6**#
##############
##############
#**3**##**6**#
#0*D*5##5*C*8#
#**0**##**8**#
##############
```

It can be seen, that the only way to "win" this board, is the way I ordered the tiles, since `<a,b>` are only connected via 2, `<a,d>` only via 3, and so on... `<a,c>,<b,d>` are not connected at all. No rotation or movement of any of the tiles will get a "win".

I wrote functions to:

1. find connections between any given 2 tiles
2. figure out how many rotations are needed to connect given 2 tiles
3. check all possibilities and find the correct order

However, this was only a simple case with 16*12*8 options, where I could rule out many options since there were unique connectors (i.e. '2' that connected `<a,c>` was not present in other tiles). If I get a bigger board (*bigger alphabet could also complicate things...*), say, 5*5, the number of options will be 100*96*92... and brute-forcing will not cut it.

How can I find the right order (the board is guaranteed to have exactly one correct order) efficiently?

Here are my efforts:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, product


# returns list of [<connector element>, <indices of element in a>, <indices of element in b>]
def find_connections(a,b):
    intersected_elem = np.array(list(set(a).intersection(b)))

    possible_connections = []

    for val in intersected_elem:
        x = list(np.where(np.array(a) == val)[0])
        y = list(np.where(np.array(b) == val)[0])
        possible_connections.append([val,x,y])

    return possible_connections

def str_tile(t, name):
    template = '''#######
#**{}**#
#{}*{}*{}#
#**{}**#
#######'''

    up,right,down,left = t

    return template.format(up,left,name.upper(),right,down)

def print_2_tiles(a,b, name_a, name_b):

    res = ''

    for line in zip(str_tile(a,name_a).splitlines(), str_tile(b,name_b).splitlines()):
        res += ''.join(line)
        res += '\n'

    return res[:-1]


def find_final_connections(tiles_ls):
    tiles_combinations = list(combinations(tiles_ls, 2))

    a_idx,b_idx = 0,1
    final_connections = []

    for comb in tiles_combinations:
        connections = find_connections(comb[0], comb[1])

        print('({},{})'.format(a_idx,b_idx), connections, end='\t')

        if len(connections):
            print('this meants {},{} are connected via {} in directions {},{}'.format(a_idx,b_idx, connections[0][0], connections[0][1][0], connections[0][2][0]))
            final_connections.append((a_idx,b_idx))
        else:
            print()

        # is there a neater way, using enumerate on itertools.combinations?
        b_idx += 1
        if b_idx == len(tiles_ls):
            a_idx += 1
            b_idx = a_idx + 1   


    print(final_connections)


a,b,c,d = [1,2,3,4], [7,9,6,2], [6,8,8,5], [3,5,0,0]
tiles_ls = [a,b,c,d]
find_final_connections(tiles_ls) # returns a 4-elem list -> success

print('#'*30)

a,b,c,d = [1,2,3,4], [7,9,6,2], [6,8,8,5], [0,5,0,0]
tiles_ls = [a,b,c,d]
find_final_connections(tiles_ls) # returns a 3-elem list -> fail
```

Comment: Please show the working brute force code you have. That will prevent the misunderstanding that you just want a program for the described requirements, without any own effort.

Comment: This is the part where I get all the possible matches. the test string is harder than the one I asked about

Comment: updated to a current working solution

Comment: How did you cont these 16x12x8 options ? A priori I see 24 permutations, each with 4^4 combinations of the rotations. An more generally (N.M)!4^(N.M), which is huge.

Comment: The OPs calculation should be 16x12x8x4, which is the same as 24 * 4^4. Either way, it vastly overestimates the number of possibilities. As soon as the first tile is placed, the number of ***legal*** moves for the second tile are greatly reduced.

Comment: I know we can reduce the legal moves, but I'm not sure how effective would that be. Assume the numbers on each tile are very much alike, and we have 100 tiles (this is my real problem - 100 tiles with numbers 1-100, where some of the numbers repeat tens of times)

Answer (score 0):

Is it so sure that brute-forcing can't do ?

I would try a systematic solution where you pick every domino in turn and place it top-left, trying all four rotations. Then pick another domino and place it in the second position, trying all four rotations and checking if there is a match with the first one.

And so on, at any stage you pick a domino from the remaining ones, try it with the four rotations and check compatibility with the known neighbors.

This is better written as a recursive procedure.